# How to create a full page overlay except 70px from the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a full page overlay div which appears on a button click and covers the full page.

```
<div class="overlay">
</div>

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 71px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

What I'd like to do is to start this overlay 70px from the top, so I can see/click/use the menu.

I've tried changing `top:70px` however it also messes up the scrolling of the overlay div (moving the bottom scroll down by 70px as well).

I believe that I need to define the height of the overlay div somehow. However, I'd rather not define a certain height in `px` but rather do something that's flexible. I've tried defining it by using % but it's not an option at all - because the screen size or the overlay's size can change anytime.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: try setting `top` and `bottom`, instead of `top` and `height`

Comment: Try adding `z-index: 100;` to  your nav

Comment: It would be much easier to just make the nav appear on top of the overlay using `z-index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a height and a width, use bottom and right:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 71px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this has worked like a charm. Easy and effective solution.

Comment: Using all 4 coordinates is pretty much how most overlays are done, it's also a good way of centring things if you give it a height and width and margin:auto - https://jsfiddle.net/9oxcxj3h/

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for this, didn't know that yet!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `height: calc(100vh - 70px);` to achieve the desired result

Comment: i was about to post this, should work. `height: 100vh; top: 70px;` for the scrolling maybe try and uping your `z-indez`